# Is there a way to use data from a YML in a Sonata Admin class of a Doctrine managed entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, sonata-admin

The situation looks like this:

- `SubscriptionPlan` entity - not managed by Doctrine, kept in an YML
  file.
- `Subscription` entity - managed by Doctrine.

Every `Subscription` has a `$subscriptionPlanJson`, that gets saved in the database, and a representation of it, `$subscriptionPlan` of type `SubscriptionPlan`, generated on `Subscription::postLoad()`.

```
class Subscription {

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", name="subscriptionPlan")
     **/
    private $subscriptionPlanJson;

    /**
     * @var SubscriptionPlan $subscriptionPlan
     */
    private $subscriptionPlan;

    // ...

}
```

In my admin I need to **display** information like `$someSubscription->getSubscriptionPlan()->getName()` on the `Subscription` edit page or to be able to filter the list by information found in `$someSubscription->getSubscriptionPlan()`, like when I need to display all subscriptions for certain plan.

Using something like this:

```
->add('subscriptionPlan', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SubscriptionPlan',
    'property' => 'type',
))
```

throws:

```
Class "AppBundle\Entity\SubscriptionPlan" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?
```

My answer to this is: No, I don't want it mapped by Doctrine. :)

Using something like:

```
->add(

    $formMapper->create('subscriptionPlanJson', 'text', array_merge(
            array(
                'label' => 'form.label_subscription_plan_json',
            ),
            'read_only' => true,
            'disabled'  => true,
    ))
    ->addViewTransformer(new SubscriptionPlanArrayToFieldTransformer('[field_name_here]'))
)
```

would only help me with displaying the information on edit page, but would not allow me to use it in listing or filters.

Can I achieve this somehow with my current setup or should I move my YML entities in the database, even though there are around 5 entries that would probably never change?